Regex to find string not followed by separator and 1 or 2 digits
I need to make a regex (.net flavour) that matches only "sometext" in the following strings (the second line has a space at the end):
sometext
sometext 
sometext dsf 2131
sometext-1234

but won't match anything in the following:
sometext  12
sometext 3
sometext2
sometext-1

That is it should match "sometext" only if it is not followed by any number of optional separator characters (like space, "-", "/", ".") and 1 or 2 digits (3 or more digits are fine).
I tried this regex with negative lookahead
sometext($|\W(?!\d{1,2}))

but didn't get too far.

What is the expected result for sometext-123.1 or sometext-12.123 or sometext-.-/.123. With $ you test the end of the input. What if the input doesn't end after three digits?

I would use the following negative lookahead approach:
sometext(?!(?:[/.-]|\s*)\d{1,2}\b)

This pattern says to match:

sometext match literal 'sometext'
(?! lookahead and negatively assert that

(?:[/.-]|\s*) what follows is not a /.- separator or zero or more whitespaces
\d{1,2}\b which is then followed by either one or two digits


) end of lookahead

Demo

Note that this matches sometext 12dfg even though it is followed by a separator and 2 digits as OP said.  Maybe better to replace the \b with [^\d] instead?

@Chris The OP gave no such sample data.  You might be right or not.

Try this one
^sometext(?![\s\-\/\.]?\d{1,2})(?!\d)

Regex explanation:

^: Matches the start of the string.
sometext: Matches the literal "sometext".
(?![\s-/.]?\d{1,2}): Negative lookahead to ensure the next character(s) aren't: An optional separator ([\s-/.]?) followed by 1–2 digits (\d{1,2}).
(?!\d): Another negative lookahead to prevent a digit immediately following "sometext".


You could make use of \W adding it to the negative lookahead:
sometext(?!\W*\d{1,2}\b)

See a regex 101 demo
Note that \W matches a non word character, which is more than only - / .

If you don't want to match 0 or more separators being one of - / . you might also use:
sometext(?![\s/.-]*\d{1,2}\b)

See another regex 101 demo
